# How does the Brainfuck Hello World actually work?

Tags: brainfuck, esoteric-languages

Someone sent this to me and claimed it is a hello world in Brainfuck (and I hope so...)

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

I know the basics that it works by moving a pointer and increment and decrementing stuff...

Yet I still want to know, how does it actually work? How does it print anything on the screen in the first place? How does it encode the text? I do not understand at all...

Comment: Must be pretty hard to maintain an application written in this language ..

Comment: @ring0: nah, that's a write-only language.

Comment: what's it's practical use ?

Comment: @YashVerma it doesn't need one..

Comment: @YashVerma It's clearly specified in the name of the language.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

## 1. Basics

To understand Brainfuck you must imagine infinite array of cells initialized by `0` each.

```
...[0][0][0][0][0]...
```

When brainfuck program starts, it points to any cell.

```
...[0][0][*0*][0][0]...
```

If you move pointer right `>` you are moving pointer from cell X to cell X+1

```
...[0][0][0][*0*][0]...
```

If you increase cell value `+` you get:

```
...[0][0][0][*1*][0]...
```

If you increase cell value again `+` you get:

```
...[0][0][0][*2*][0]...
```

If you decrease cell value `-` you get:

```
...[0][0][0][*1*][0]...
```

If you move pointer left `<` you are moving pointer from cell X to cell X-1

```
...[0][0][*0*][1][0]...
```

## 2. Input

To read character you use comma `,`. What it does is: *Read character from standard input and write its decimal ASCII code to the actual cell.*

Take a look at [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). For example, decimal code of `!` is `33`, while `a` is `97`.

Well, lets imagine your BF program memory looks like:

```
...[0][0][*0*][0][0]...
```

Assuming standard input stands for `a`, if you use comma `,` operator, what BF does is read `a` decimal ASCII code `97` to memory:

```
...[0][0][*97*][0][0]...
```

You generally want to think that way, however the truth is a bit more complex. The truth is BF does not read a character but a byte (whatever that byte is). Let me show you example:

In linux

```
$ printf ł
```

prints:

```
ł
```

which is specific polish character. This character is not encoded by ASCII encoding. In this case it's UTF-8 encoding, so it used to take more than one byte in computer memory. We can prove it by making a hexadecimal dump:

```
$ printf ł | hd
```

which shows:

```
00000000  c5 82                                             |..|
```

Zeroes are offset. `82` is first and `c5` is second byte representing `ł` (in order we will read them). `|..|` is graphical representation which is not possible in this case.

Well, if you pass `ł` as input to your BF program that reads single byte, program memory will look like:

```
...[0][0][*197*][0][0]...
```

Why `197` ? Well `197` decimal is `c5` hexadecimal. Seems familiar ? Of course. It's first byte of `ł` !

## 3. Output

To print character you use dot `.` What it does is: *Assuming we treat actual cell value like decimal ASCII code, print corresponding character to standard output.*

Well, lets imagine your BF program memory looks like:

```
...[0][0][*97*][0][0]...
```

If you use dot (.) operator now, what BF does is print:

> a

Because `a` decimal code in ASCII is `97`.

So for example BF program like this (97 pluses 2 dots):

> +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++..

Will increase value of the cell it points to up to 97 and print it out 2 times.

> aa

## 4. Loops

In BF loop consists of loop begin `[` and loop end `]`. You can think it's like while in C/C++ where the condition is actual cell value.

Take a look BF program below:

```
++[]
```

`++` increments actual cell value twice:

```
...[0][0][*2*][0][0]...
```

And `[]` is like `while(2) {}`, so it's infinite loop.

Let's say we don't want this loop to be infinite. We can do for example:

```
++[-]
```

So each time a loop loops it decrements actual cell value. Once actual cell value is `0` loop ends:

```
...[0][0][*2*][0][0]...        loop starts
...[0][0][*1*][0][0]...        after first iteration
...[0][0][*0*][0][0]...        after second iteration (loop ends)
```

Let's consider yet another example of finite loop:

```
++[>]
```

This example shows, we haven't to finish loop at cell that loop started on:

```
...[0][0][*2*][0][0]...        loop starts
...[0][0][2][*0*][0]...        after first iteration (loop ends)
```

However it is good practice to end where we started. Why ? Because if loop ends another cell it started, we can't assume where the cell pointer will be. To be honest, this practice makes brainfuck less brainfuck.

Comment: Cool, now I understood it :)

Comment: What about `,` `[` and `]`? :(

Comment: Generally my goal was just to explain bf ideology, but you're right. I ll boost my answer soon.

Comment: That was a perfect solution to the novice trying to comprehend this language ideology.  Congrats, and great post.

Comment: Best Brainfuck intro I've seen. Honestly you undo BF a bit by your post

Comment: @Scony the real (Brain)f*ckers don't care about Da Rulez: `$ echo "++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>->+>>+[<]<-]>>.>>---.+++++++..+++.>.<<-.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>++." | bf` `Hello world!`

Comment: This is the best way I can understand the Brainf*** language! Now I know how my custom Brainf*** interpreter converts the code to a string!

Comment: I guess that if you need a project for your spare time, you can always add Unicode support to Brainfuck.

Comment: After your post, BF is !BF anymore!

Comment: a perfect introduction; I guess that the biggest value of BF is in creating unusually looking and puzzling code patterns

Answer (score 58):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) has a commented version of the code.

```
+++++ +++++             initialize counter (cell #0) to 10
[                       use loop to set the next four cells to 70/100/30/10
    > +++++ ++              add  7 to cell #1
    > +++++ +++++           add 10 to cell #2 
    > +++                   add  3 to cell #3
    > +                     add  1 to cell #4
    <<<< -                  decrement counter (cell #0)
]                   
> ++ .                  print 'H'
> + .                   print 'e'
+++++ ++ .              print 'l'
.                       print 'l'
+++ .                   print 'o'
> ++ .                  print ' '
<< +++++ +++++ +++++ .  print 'W'
> .                     print 'o'
+++ .                   print 'r'
----- - .               print 'l'
----- --- .             print 'd'
> + .                   print '!'
> .                     print '\n'
```

To answer your questions, the `,` and `.` characters are used for I/O. The text is ASCII.

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) article goes on in some more depth, as well.

> The first line initialises `a[0] = 10` by simply incrementing ten times
>   from 0. The loop from line 2 effectively sets the initial values for
>   the array: `a[1] = 70` (close to 72, the ASCII code for the character
>   'H'), `a[2] = 100` (close to 101 or 'e'), `a[3] = 30` (close to 32, the
>   code for space) and `a[4] = 10` (newline). The loop works by adding 7,
>   10, 3, and 1, to cells `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]` and `a[4]` respectively each
>   time through the loop - 10 additions for each cell in total (giving
>   `a[1]=70` etc.). After the loop is finished, `a[0]` is zero. `>++.` then
>   moves the pointer to `a[1]`, which holds 70, adds two to it (producing
>   72, which is the ASCII character code of a capital H), and outputs it.
>
> The next line moves the array pointer to `a[2]` and adds one to it,
>   producing 101, a lower-case 'e', which is then output.
>
> As 'l' happens
>   to be the seventh letter after 'e', to output 'll' another seven are
>   added (`+++++++`) to `a[2]` and the result is output twice.
>
> 'o' is the
>   third letter after 'l', so `a[2]` is incremented three more times and
>   output the result.
>
> The rest of the program goes on in the same way.
>   For the space and capital letters, different array cells are selected
>   and incremented or decremented as needed.

Comment: But WHY it prints? or how? The comments are explaining to me the intent of the line, now what it do.

Comment: It prints because the compiler knows that `,` and `.` are used for I/O, much like C prints by using `putchar`. It is an implementation detail handled by the compiler.

Comment: And also because it's setting the required cells to the integer values for the ASCII characters in "Hello World"

Comment: I expected a more in depth explanation... but :/

Comment: @speeder - I added the in-depth explanation of the code from Wikipedia to the answer. You can see the linked article for more information.

Answer (score 12):

**Brainfuck** 
same as its name.
It uses only 8 characters `> [ . ] , -  +` which makes it the **quickest** programming language **to learn** but **hardest to** implement and **understand.**
….and makes you finally end up with f*cking your brain.

It stores values in array: [72 ][101 ][108 ][111 ]

let, initially pointer pointing to cell 1 of array:

1. `>` move pointer to right by 1
2. `<` move pointer to left by 1
3. `+` increment the value of cell by 1
4. `-` increment the value of element by 1
5. `.` print value of current cell.
6. `,` take input to current cell.
7. `[ ]` loop, +++[ -] counter of 3 counts bcz it have 3 ′+’ before it, and - decrements count variable by 1 value.

the values stored in cells are ascii values:

so referring to above array: [72 ][101 ][108 ][108][111 ]
if you match the ascii values you’ll find that it is **Hello** writtern

**Congrats!** you have learned the syntax of BF

——-**Something more** ———

let us make our first program i.e **Hello World**, after which you’re able to write your name in this language.

```
+++++ +++++[> +++++ ++ >+++++ +++++ >+++ >+ <<<-]>++.>+.+++++ ++..+++.++.+++++ +++++ +++++.>.+++.----- -.----- ---.>+.>.
```

breaking into pieces:

```
+++++ +++++[> +++++ ++ 
                  >+++++ +++++ 
                  >+++ 
                  >+ 
                  <<<-]
```

Makes an array of 4 cells(number of >) and sets a counter of 10 something like :
—-psuedo code—-

```
array =[7,10,3,1]
i=10
while i>0:
 element +=element
 i-=1
```

because counter value is stored in cell 0 and > moves to cell 1 updates its value by+7 > moves to cell 2 increments 10 to its previous value and so on….

`<<<` return to cell 0 and decrements its value by 1

hence after loop completion we have array : [70,100,30,10]

```
>++.
```

moves to 1st element and increment its value by 2(two ‘+’) and then prints(‘.’) character with that ascii value. i.e for example  in python:
chr(70+2) # prints 'H'

```
>+.
```

moves to 2nd cell increment 1 to its value 100+1 and prints(‘.’) its value i.e chr(101)
chr(101) #prints ‘e’
now there is no > or < in next piece so it takes present value of latest element and increment to it only

```
+++++ ++..
```

latest element = 101 therefore, 101+7 and prints it twice(as there are two‘..’) chr(108) #prints l twice
can be used as

```
for i in array:
    for j in range(i.count(‘.’)):
           print_value
```

———**Where is it used?**——-

It is just a joke language made to challenge programmers and is not used practically anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question of how it knows what to print, I have added the calculation of ASCII values to the right of the code where the printing happens:

```
> just means move to the next cell
< just means move to the previous cell
+ and - are used for increment and decrement respectively. The value of the cell is updated when the increment/decrement happens

+++++ +++++             initialize counter (cell #0) to 10

[                       use loop to set the next four cells to 70/100/30/10

> +++++ ++              add  7 to cell #1

> +++++ +++++           add 10 to cell #2 

> +++                   add  3 to cell #3

> +                     add  1 to cell #4

<<<< -                  decrement counter (cell #0)

]            

> ++ .                  print 'H' (ascii: 70+2 = 72) //70 is value in current cell. The two +s increment the value of the current cell by 2

> + .                   print 'e' (ascii: 100+1 = 101)

+++++ ++ .              print 'l' (ascii: 101+7 = 108)

.                       print 'l' dot prints same thing again

+++ .                   print 'o' (ascii: 108+3 = 111)

> ++ .                  print ' ' (ascii: 30+2 = 32)

<< +++++ +++++ +++++ .  print 'W' (ascii: 72+15 = 87)

> .                     print 'o' (ascii: 111)

+++ .                   print 'r' (ascii: 111+3 = 114)

----- - .               print 'l' (ascii: 114-6 = 108)

----- --- .             print 'd' (ascii: 108-8 = 100)

> + .                   print '!' (ascii: 32+1 = 33)

> .                     print '\n'(ascii: 10)
```

Answer (score 5):

All the answers are thorough, but they lack one tiny detail: Printing.
In building your brainfuck translator, you also consider the character `.`, this is actually what a printing statement looks like in brainfuck. So what your brainfuck translator should do is, whenever it encounters a `.` character it prints the currently pointed byte.

**Example:**

suppose you have --> `char *ptr = [0] [0] [0] [97] [0]`...
if this is a brainfuck statement:    `>>>.` your pointer should be moved 3 spaces to right landing at: `[97]`, so now `*ptr = 97`, after doing that your translator encounters a `.`, it should then call

```
write(1, ptr, 1)
```

or any equivalent printing statement to print the currently pointed byte, which has the value **97** and the letter `a` will then be printed on the `std_output`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is how does Brainfuck know what to do with all the code. There is a parser written in a higher level language such as Python to interpret what a dot means, or what an addition sign means in the code.

So the parser will read your code line by line, and say ok there is a > symbol so i have to advance memory location, the code is simply, if (contents in that memory location) == >, memlocation =+ memlocation which is written in a higher level language, similarly if (content in memory location) == ".", then print (contents of memory location).

Hope this clears it up. tc